Virtuelle List error in FlatList- React native
When pressing the "Update" Button I get this Error:
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 4602, "dt": 4263, "prevDt": 3957} 
Can someone take a quick look and help me find the error? I read about useMemo and useCallback but can't really understand when to use it. Is it really necessary?
Also when updating it's not jumping to the top of the List. just a few posts higher.
This is my index:
import { StyleSheet, Pressable, Alert, Button } from "react-native";
import { View, SafeAreaView, Text } from "components/Themed";
import { Image } from "expo-image";
import Colors from "constants/Colors";
import fetchNews from "components/fetchNews";
import { FlatList, useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { useAuthStore } from "components/authStore";
import { supabase } from "@/utils/supabase";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";
import { Link } from "expo-router";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { RefreshControl } from "react-native";
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { useRef, useMemo } from "react";

export default function index() {
  const { posts, fetchError, refetch, updateAvailable, applyUpdates } =
    fetchNews();

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const themeErrorStyle = useMemo(
    () =>
      colorScheme === "light" ? styles.lightThemeError : styles.darkThemeError,
    [colorScheme]
  );

  const themeContainerStyle = useMemo(
    () =>
      colorScheme === "light" ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer,
    [colorScheme]
  );

  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuthStore();

  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const scrollRef = useRef();

  // Display refresh screen
  const refresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    // Get changes
    refetch().finally(() => {
      setRefreshing(false);
    });
  }, []);

  const deletePost = (id) => {
    Alert.alert("Beitrag wirklich löschen?", "", [
      {
        text: "Abbrechen",
        style: "cancel",
        onPress: () => console.log("Ask me later pressed"),
      },
      {
        text: "Ja",
        onPress: () => removePost(id),
      },
    ]);

    const removePost = async (id) => {
      const { error } = await supabase.from("News").delete().eq("id", id);

      if (error) {
        Toast.show({
          type: "error",
          text1: "Fehler beim löschen eines Beitrags!",
          text2: "Versuch es später nochmal!",
        });
      } else {
        Toast.show({
          type: "success",
          text1: "Beitrag erfolgreich gelöscht!",
        });
      }
    };
  };

  const updateNews = useCallback(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true });
    refresh();
    applyUpdates();
  }, [applyUpdates]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Neuigkeiten</Text>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Link href='/adminDashboard' asChild>
            <Pressable>
              <MaterialIcons
                name='add-circle-outline'
                size={34}
                color='black'
              />
            </Pressable>
          </Link>
        ) : null}
      </View>

      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        {updateAvailable && (
          <View style={styles.updateContainer}>
            <Pressable style={styles.updateButton} onPress={() => updateNews()}>
             ** <Text style={styles.updateButtonText}>Update</Text>**
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        )}
        {fetchError ? (
          <View style={styles.renderError}>
            <Text style={[styles.errorText, themeErrorStyle]}>
              {fetchError}
            </Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={posts}
            ref={scrollRef}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={refresh} />
            }
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={[styles.newsContainer, themeContainerStyle]}>
                <View style={styles.newsHeader}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.newsImage}
                    source={require("assets/images/indexIcon.png")}
                    contentFit='contain'
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.newsHeaderText}>Sayyid </Text>
                  {isLoggedIn ? (
                    <FontAwesome
                      name='trash-o'
                      size={24}
                      color='red'
                      onPress={() => deletePost(item.id)}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.newsContentTextContainer}>
                  {item.title && (
                    <Text style={styles.newsTitleText}>{item.title}</Text>
                  )}
                  {item.content && (
                    <Text style={styles.newsContentText}>{item.content}</Text>
                  )}
                  {item.imagePath && (
                    <View style={styles.newsImageContainer}>
                      <Image
                        style={styles.newsImage}
                        source={{
                          uri: item.imagePath,
                        }}
                      />
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 0.1,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 14,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 0.9,
  },
  newsContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  newsHeader: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  newsImage: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
  },
  newsHeaderText: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
  newsContentTextContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  newsTitleText: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    paddingBottom: 15,
  },
  newsContentText: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 28,
  },
  newsImageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  newsImage: {
    width: "100%", // Beispielbreite in einer reaktionsfähigen Einheit
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 0.8,
  },

  renderError: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    paddingRight: 12,
  },
  errorText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.light.error,
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  lightThemeError: { color: Colors.light.error },
  darkThemeError: { color: Colors.light.error },
  lightContainer: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.light.white,
  },
  darkContainer: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.dark.contrast,
  },
  updateContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  updateButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#2ecc71",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  updateButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 6,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: Colors.light.black,
  },
});



And this is my fetchNews:
import { supabase } from "@/utils/supabase";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function fetchNews() {
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState<string>("");
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [updateAvailable, setUpdateAvailable] = useState(false);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("Name")
      .select("*")
      .order("id", { ascending: false });

    // Error checking

    if (error) {
      setFetchError(
        "Neuigkeiten konnten nicht geladen werden.\n Überprüfen Sie bitte Ihre Internetverbindung!"
      );
      setPosts([]);
    }

    if (data) {
      setPosts(data);
      setFetchError("");
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();

    const subscription = supabase
      .channel("Name")
      .on(
        "postgres_changes",
        { event: "INSERT", schema: "public", table: "Name" },
        (payload) => {
          setUpdateAvailable(true);
        }
      )
      .on(
        "postgres_changes",
        { event: "DELETE", schema: "public", table: "Name" },
        (payload) => {
          setUpdateAvailable(true);
        }
      )
      .subscribe();

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const applyUpdates = () => {
    setUpdateAvailable(false);
  };

  return {
    fetchError,
    posts,
    refetch: fetchItems,
    updateAvailable,
    applyUpdates,
  };
}


googling and reading about useCallback and useMemo
